# Matplotlib Switch X and Y Axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a seemingly simple question that I can't figure out. The code below products the chart below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({.5:[0,0,0], .6:[1,2,1], .7:[7,8,6], .8:[23,33,21], .9: 
[84,126,76] }, index=['Desktop', 'Mobile', 'Table'])
df.T.plot(figsize=(10,10))
```

[image]

This is almost what I want, but I need percentile on the Y-Axis and Days on the X-Axis. Thanks for the help.

Comment: what happens if you don't transpose the dataframe?

Comment: I am already transposing the dataframe. If I don't transpose the dataframe I don't get what I want.

Comment: I recommend explicitly specifying x and y per the docstring of `DataFrame.plot.line`

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that too, but I keep getting an error. I guess I will keep playing around with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clean up your data into a [tidy](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html) format, then specify your matplotlib axes, and the x- & y- values explicitly:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    0.5: [0, 0, 0],
    0.6: [1, 2, 1],
    0.7: [7, 8, 6],
    0.8: [23, 33, 21],
    0.9: [84, 126, 76]
}, index=['Desktop', 'Mobile', 'Tablet'])

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
groups = (
    df.T
      .stack()
      .rename_axis(['pctile', 'device'])
      .to_frame('days')
      .reset_index()
      .groupby(by=['device'])
)
for device, g in groups:
    g.plot.line(ax=ax, x='days', y='pctile', label=device)
```

[image]